Teachable Machine Keras Model Load Issue
from keras.models import load_model  # TensorFlow is required for Keras to work
from PIL import Image, ImageOps  # Install pillow instead of PIL
import numpy as np

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = load_model("keras_Model.h5", compile=False)

# Load the labels
class_names = open("labels.txt", "r").readlines()

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open("/chest_xray/val/PNEUMONIA/person1_virus_9.jpeg").convert("RGB")

# resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

# turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.5) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# Predicts the model
prediction = model.predict(data)
index = np.argmax(prediction)
class_name = class_names[index]
confidence_score = prediction[0][index]

# Print prediction and confidence score
print("Class:", class_name[2:], end="")
print("Confidence Score:", confidence_score)

I am trying to load a keras model that I have trained using the Teachable Machine website on my local device and I have copied the code from the website as well. However when I am trying to load the model it give me the following error.
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'DepthwiseConv2D' using config={'name': 'expanded_conv_depthwise', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'same', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'linear', 'use_bias': False, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'depth_multiplier': 1, 'depthwise_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'scale': 1, 'mode': 'fan_avg', 'distribution': 'uniform', 'seed': None}}, 'depthwise_regularizer': None, 'depthwise_constraint': None}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}

I assumed that the issue was due to some incompatible tensorflow and keras packages but I've checked and that seems to be fine. Here are the versions I have installed.
keras == 3.2.1
tensorflow == 2.16.1
I have tried installing various different versions to solve this but I am still facing the same problem.

It appears that the model was trained using certain layer configurations or settings that are not fully compatible with the version of Keras you are currently using (Keras==3.2.1).This can occur with custom layers or specific configurations that may have changed between different versions of Keras. To resolve this issue, ensure that the Keras version (Keras==3.2.1) you used during training precisely matches the version you are using now to load the model. Ideally, try to align the Keras version in your current environment with the exact version that was used when model was originally trained

Thanks. You are right there was some compatibility issues with the version used for training. Was able to fix it by installing a previous version of Keras and using Python 3.9.
